# Rotate text (90º degree - vertical rotation) in Odoo 10 QWeb PDF report

Tags: odoo, qweb

I need to rotate text by 90º (to display it vertically) in a custom QWeb PDF report.

Could someone paste an specific CSS and HTML example to do so?

(Odoo 10)

Thanks

Comment: transform:rotate(90deg);

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works in Odoo 11:

```
<div style="transform: rotate(90deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);">Rotated Text</div>
```

I had much trouble with it myself, because `transform: rotate(90deg);` rotated the text in the preview, but it did not print so. The version of wkhtmltopdf used in Odoo 11 does not support this CSS property unless prefixed (and wkthmltopdf uses a Webkit rendering engine).

If this does not work in Odoo 10 or previous, you will need to see if you can update, or at least update wkhtmltopdf to a version that supports that property.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello usk70,**

**Definition and Usage**
The transform property applies a 2D or 3D transformation to an element. This property allows you to rotate, scale, move, skew, etc., elements.

**Syntax**
transform: none|transform-functions|initial|inherit;

**Property Values**
rotate(angle) : Defines a 2D rotation, the angle is specified in the parameter

**For Example,**
I give the example using html and css3 and try this code in your odoo 10 qweb pdf report.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Hello </div>
<br>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the transform property.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9 supports an alternative, the -ms-transform property. Newer versions of IE support the transform property (do not need the ms prefix).</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Chrome, Safari and Opera supports an alternative, the -webkit-transform property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope my answer is helpfull.
If any query so comment please.

Comment: I was never able to make this work in Odoo. I have this need again. Can you provide a working example in Odoo?